# Getting random FPS drop on almost every game, not a throttling issue

Tags: technical-issues, performance

Since some time (1 month I think) I had this problem, some games were going as low as 20-30 FPS for some second and then returning to the standard 60-80FPS I'm used to getting. However this suddenly became worse. I can't find out what's causing this.

I'm using an HP Pavilion AK112NL Gaming Laptop, I7 6700HQ and GTX950M 4GB, 8GB ram, win 10 Home 1803 (build 17134.112).

This is not a thermal throttling issue, I ran the games in windowed mode while keeping an eye at CPU and GPU temperature using throttlestop, HWonitor and MSI afterburner, fps drops were happening at 75-80C.

Laptop is also set to maximum performance mode. I tried to update both NVidia and intel drivers with no luck, I changed thermal paste 1 week ago, still no luck (but I lowered my temps by 5-10 degrees).

Tried a fresh install today and still nothing.

When the drops happen there is no relevant disk activity. I also tried with games both on SSD and HDD and there is no difference. Still getting FPS drops.

These drops happen on: Warframe, war thunder, Starcraft II, Wreckfest, Euro Truck simulator 2, Grid: Autosport, The Incredible adventures of van helsing, CS:GO and so on. Various genres of games, various type of GPU and CPU load, same problem.

I have disabled Game DVR on windows, removed GeForce Experience and still no difference.

I've never seen something like this in years of PC gaming. Any ideas on how to remove this problem?

Comment: I have similar problem when I unplug my laptop and plug it back in. It never changes back to high performance mode even though it says it does. It is probably not the same for you. You might also try asking in different stack exchange website possibly super User might be good

Comment: This seems to be a common problem which is suspected of being caused by a Windows update.  Here is a 308(!)-page thread about it on the NVidia forums: [All games stuttering with FPS drops since Windows 10 Creators Update](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/1004600/all-games-stuttering-with-fps-drops-since-windows-10-creators-update/?offset=0)  No idea whether either Microsoft or NVidia has ever stepped up to take responsibility, figure out a fix, and so forth.  I have the same problem and have for months, and the game doesn't have to be graphically-intensive for it to happen.

Comment: By the way, I've had better luck by switching to only one monitor instead of two while I play a graphically-intensive game.  It doesn't completely solve the slowdowns, but it at least makes them much less common, and quicker to resolve.

Comment: I get this in some games when I leave Chrome running... no idea what its doing... but its definatley the cause as I close it and everything is normal. (I7 4700HQ, 12GB Ram, Nvidia Geforce 860M,).If you suspect its windows update, MANUALLY force update checks and installed... don't wait for them to be forced on you.

Comment: Another thing to check: Are you definitely using the GTX?  A lot of systems these days might include an integrated graphics card.  On my Surface Book 2, I've found that usually when there are performance problems, it's because the integrated graphics card is being used instead of the "good" card.  There's an nVidia control panel to fix this, but unfortunately it's either per-game (so I have to set it individually for everything) or it's for everything (meaning I can't undock my laptop screen because the graphics card in the base is in use).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and for me it was OneDrive, checking for something to sync. There was nothing to sync even, but it stopped when I closed it.

This happened to me in Heroes of the Storm, which doesn't need anything powerful.

I would imagine that any other cloudstorage could have same impact: DropBox, Google Drive, Amazon, ... you name it.

Ensure the app is stopped when playing (and not running in tray!).

Comment: I will try closing OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

I get this a lot as well, It's usually to do with other tabs taking up your CPU, Disk or memory. Make sure you have no background apps open when you're playing your game, such as Chrome, etc.